# BottleフレームワークでDynamic Routingのフィルターを機能させる方法

Tags: python, bottle

PythonのWebアプリケーションフレームワークであるBottleのチュートリアルを使用しているのですが、その中でDynamic Routingのfilterのところで詰まってしまっています。

具体的には以下のコードを実行します。

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/object/<id:int>')
def callback(id):
    assert isinstance(id, int)

@route('/show/<name:re:[a-z]+')
def callback(name):
    assert name.isalpha()

@route('/static/<path:path>')
def callback(path):
    return static_file(path,null)

run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True, debug=True)
```

その後ブラウザから`http://localhost:8080/object/192`にアクセスすると次のように出力されます。

```
192 object
```

Pythonの[公式ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)を見ると`isinstance()`はTrueもしくはFalseを戻り値として返すようなので、Trueが出力されるのが正しいのではないかと考えているのですが、`192 object`が正しいのでしょうか。そうでない場合、記載したコードに誤りがあればご指摘いただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: すいませんコードの一部だけになっていたので不足分を記載します

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@route('/')
@route('/hello/<name>')
def greet(name='Stranger'):
    return template('Hello {{name}}, how are you?', name=name)

@route('/wiki/<pagename>')
def show_wiki_page(pagename):
    return template('Now you see the {{pagename}} wiki.', pagename=pagename)

@route('/<action>/<user>')
def user_api(action, user):
    return template('{{user}} {{action}}', user=user, action=action)

@route('/object/<id:int>')

Comment: こちらの環境(Python 2.7.12, bottle 0.12.9)では何も表示されません。確かに `isinstance()` は `True/False` を返しますが、`assert` を実行しているので結果が `True` であれば何も表示されないはずです。

Comment: @metropolis 様
回答ありがとうございます。`assert`を実行している場合は結果が`True`の時には何も表示されないのですね。
勉強になります。

Comment: これは `@route('/<action>/<user>')` のルーティングが原因ですね…。

Comment: あ、本当だ。。。
随分と初歩的なところでつまずいていたとは。。。
お手数おかけしました。

Answer (score 0):

`@route('/<action>/<user>')` のルーティングが原因です。
`@route('/object/<id:int>')` とバッティングしているため、先に記述されている`user_api`関数が呼ばれます。
`@route('/<action>/<user>')` を削除するか、この`user_api`関数を`callback`関数の後に記述することで回避できます。

また、`assert`はエラーの時のみエラーを返します。
True, Falseを返したい時は`return str(isinstance(id, int))`などで文字列を返さないと正しく表示されません。

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!" 

@route('/')
@route('/hello/<name>')
def greet(name='Stranger'):
    return template('Hello {{name}}, how are you?', name=name)

@route('/wiki/<pagename>')
def show_wiki_page(pagename):
    return template('Now you see the {{pagename}} wiki.', pagename=pagename)

@route('/<action>/<user>')          #バッティング
def user_api(action, user):
    return template('{{user}} {{action}}', user=user, action=action)

@route('/object/<id:int>')
def callback(id):
    assert isinstance(id, int)      #間違っている時にエラーを返す
    return str(isinstance(id, int)) #True, Falseを返す

@route('/show/<name:re:[a-z]+')
def callback(name):
    assert name.isalpha()

@route('/static/<path:path>')
def callback(path):
    return static_file(path,null)

run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True, debug=True)
```

---

<sup>この投稿は @metropolis さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/30372/#comment29364_30372)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>